# What are closed and discrete sets in general topology?

Tags: general-topology

I have some idea about  closed sets as well as discrete sets in general topology but i'm confused about closed discrete sets . can any one please help me out  about  that what type of the sets are closed discrete sets in general topology?

Comment: They are the compliment of the open sets relative to the whole topological space. Do you know what the open sets are in the discrete topology?

Comment: By closed discrete sets, do you mean sets which are both closed and discrete in the usual topology? Like $\{0\}$ , for example?

Answer (score 2):

A set $C \subseteq X$ is closed and discrete when

- for all $x \in C$ we have an open set $O$ containing $x$ such that $O \cap C= \{x\}$ (discreteness)
- for all $x \notin C$ we have an open set $O$ containing $x$ such that $O \cap C = \emptyset$ (closedness).

Summarised: for all $x \in X$ we have an open neighbourhood of $x$ such that $O \cap C \subseteq \{x\}$.

Examples include all finite sets in a $T_1$ space, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology, $\{\frac{1}{n}: n=1,2,3,4,\ldots\} \subseteq (0,1]$ in the usual topology.

A space is countably compact iff it has no infinite closed discrete subspace.

In a metric space $X$, $X$ is separable iff all closed and discrete subspaces are at most countable.